# Rails DB Indexing: Is this an anti-pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, indexing

Would setting up indexes like this in a Rails 4 app (using Postgresql) be considered okay if I think the queries my app runs warrants them? Just checking as I am not an index pro and I don't want to cause performance issues by accident. The example below is supposed to be a join table. Thanks!

```
add_index "foo_bars", ["foo_id", "bar_id"]
add_index "foo_bars", "foo_id"
add_index "foo_bars", "bar_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably only need two indexes. Do you commonly query using both columns? If so, do this:

```
add_index "foo_bars", ["foo_id", "bar_id"]
add_index "foo_bars", ["bar_id", "foo_id"]
```

With those two, your DB should find an appropriate index no matter which column(s) you're querying on. It probably doesn't save any space, but it means your DB only has to update two indexes when your data changes (not that you're likely to notice the speed difference).

However, I'm willing to bet your queries typically only include `foo_id` OR `bar_id` (not both), since you're probably just traversing the `has_many` relationship most of the time. If that's the case, just define the indexes on individual columns. PostgreSQL is smart enough to merge the indexes when you query on both columns.

```
add_index "foo_bars", "foo_id"
add_index "foo_bars", "bar_id"
```

Comment: Actually, in PostgreSQL you only need an index on `(foo, bar)` and one on `bar` alone to cover all possibilities (assuming you need that at all). PostgreSQL can use the index on `(foo, bar)` efficiently for queries against `foo` but not against `bar` - it can use composite indexes with partially matching columns so long as the left-most columns match. As you note, though, it can fall back to a bitmap index scan on two different indexes too.